# How to disable <br type="_moz" in contentEditable div in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

Firefox automatically inserts a

```
 <br type="_moz">
```

in contentEditable divs on press of enter key. It also adds a <br> automatically when I insert any element through document.execCommand.

This behavior is not present in other browsers.

How to prevent this from happening in firefox.

Comment: You need to filter those tags out either while typing. Or clean up the code as a post process step. contentEditable is still a _problematic_ feature because a the various difference between the browsers. Depending on the use-case you should think over using a library that will take care about those problems for you.

Comment: So far no concrete solution to this problem ? @Aniket

Comment: @agpt I am not sure. But it seems there is still no concrete solution to this. I did solve the problem but by myself by writing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can try add `onchange="$(this).children('br[type=\"_moz\"]').remove();"` on your div. It will destroy any childrens of div with `type='_moz'` at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to have fixed,
but I think this is where you are looking for:

```html
<br type=""/>
```